# Group view of ExpandableListView inflate error

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I am implementing an `ExpandableListView` in my project and i have the following problem.

I have a variable called `Type` in the list i supply to my `expandablelistview adapter` which `extends` `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. Based on the value of `type` (1, 2 or 3 only) i am inflating one of 3 different layouts. my `getGroupView()` is thus,

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final int type =  ((cast) getGroup(groupPosition)).getType();

    if(convertView == null){
        if(type == 1){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, parent, false);
        }else if(type == 2){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, parent, false);
        }else if(type == 3){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout3, parent, false);
        }   
    }

    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvID);

    text.setText("some text");

    return convertView;
}
```

So, when the `activity` initially loads, everything is fine. But when i expand the first group, the `layout` of the groups below gets altered as well. Expand the second group and the `layout` of the groups 3,4,5,...(but not 1) get altered and so on. When i collapse everything is fine.

What seems to be the problem here ? Am i missing anything ? Is my approach right ?

Also since i am inflating 3 different `layout`s, how do i get a reference to different elements(imageview, textview,...) in those layouts so that i can populate them with required values ?

EDIT : Full adapter implementation

```
public class EventExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

/* Class1 {
    var1;
    var2;
    ...
    ArrayList<Class2> var3;
}
*/

Context context;
final List<Class1> events;

public EventExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Class1> events) {
    this.context = context;
    this.events = events;
}


@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return events.get(groupPosition).getVar3().get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null){

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childlayout, parent, false);
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return events.get(groupPosition).getVar3().size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return events.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return events.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final int type =  ((cast) getGroup(groupPosition)).getType();

    if(convertView == null){
        if(type == 1){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, parent, false);
        }else if(type == 2){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, parent, false);
        }else if(type == 3){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout3, parent, false);
        }   
    }

    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvID);

    text.setText("some text");

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

}
```

EDIT 2 : I tried to create the illusion of 3 different layouts by using only 1 layout and hiding/showing different view based on the value of type. Still the same result.

Comment: Update your Question with complete adapter

Answer (score 0):

Start from 0 to check condition of type like:

```
    if(type == 0){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, parent, false);
    }else if(type == 1){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, parent, false);
    }else if(type == 2){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout3, parent, false);
    }
```

Comment: The value of type is something that i have hard coded for testing purpose.. I know the exact value.. How does your solution help ?